# When is a bijective map between bundles a homeomorphism?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $F \rightarrow E_i \rightarrow X_i$ be a bundle with fibre $F$  for i=1,2.
Let $f:E_1 \rightarrow  E_2$ be a bijective continuous map and $h: X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ a homeomorphism.

Is f then also a heomeomorphism? 
If not, what further properties are needed for f to be a hemeomorphism?

Comment: What does $h$ have to do with it?

Comment: There should probably be some sort of commutative diagram.

Comment: Do you requre that $f$ descends to $h$? If so, the question makes sense, but the answer is obvious: $f$ need not be a homeomorphism, e.g. take $X_i$ to be a single point (or more generally, let the bundles be trivial), but choose $f$ so that its inverse discontinuous.

Comment: Take $F$ to be a space admitting a self-bijection that is not a homeomorphism, and take $X$ to be a one-point space.  More generally, an obvious necessary condition for a general result is that every continuous bijection of $F$ be a homeomorphism.

Comment: what is a heomeomorphism?

Comment: I think there are cases where you are in luck, for example vector bundles. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been pointed out in the comments that this sort of thing cannot hold for arbitrary fiber bundles.

To follow up on euklid345's comment regarding vector bundles, there is a statement of this type for arbitrary principal bundles, assuming the appropriate definitions.  There's a detailed discussion of this in my course notes, available at http://sofia.nmsu.edu/~ramras/601.html (see p. 15 of Lectures 3-5).  I believe it's also somewhere in Husemoller's book.

Comment: And for vector bundles, there's a nice discussion in Milnor and Stasheff.